# How to insert DDMMYYYY value in DATE datatype column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created table with following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_CUSTOMERS 
(
    CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_OPEN_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    LAST_CUNSULTED_DATE DATE,
    VACCINATION_TYPE CHAR(5),
    DOCTOR_CONSULTED CHAR(5),
    STATE CHAR(5),
    COUNTRY CHAR(5),
    POST_CODE INT,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,
    ACTIVE_CUSTOMER CHAR(1)
)
```

I want to insert following values

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_ID,
                            CUSTOMER_OPEN_DATE, LAST_CUNSULTED_DATE,
                            VACCINATION_TYPE, DOCTOR_CONSULTED,
                            STATE, COUNTRY, DATE_OF_BIRTH, ACTIVE_CUSTOMER) 
VALUES ('ALEX', '123457', '20101012', '20121013', 'MVD', 'PAUL', 'SA', 'USA', '06031987', 'A'),
       ('JOHN', '123458', '20101012', '20121013', 'MVD', NULL, 'TN', 'IND', '06031987', 'A'),
       ('MATHEW', '123459', '20101012', '20121013', 'MVD', NULL, 'WAS', 'PHIL', '06031987', 'A'),
       ('MATT', '12345', '20101012', '20121013', 'MVD', NULL, 'BOS', 'NYC', '06031987', 'A'),
       ('JACOB', '1256', '20101012', '20121013', 'MVD', NULL, 'VIC', 'AU', '6031987', 'A')
```

But I'm getting an error while inserting `06031987` value into `DATE_OF_BIRTH` column. I tried convert, cast, set dateformat... but no success.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Don't use that format, use `yyyyMMdd`, it's unambiguous.

Comment: To echo Larnu, I can't even tell if that's June 3rd or March 6th, except that your question title says `ddmmyyyy`. This is just not a valid format - fix the source to use a proper, unambiguous, non-regional format.

Comment: Your other dates clearly use a different format. Possibly even the correct format. So, why on earth are you trying to also accept a different (nonsense) format for the dob? Whatever is supplying or preprocessing this data needs to be fixed.

Comment: Also I hope `6031987` was a typo isolated to your question. If you are stuck with garbage but can't even rely on the source to provide _consistent_ garbage I don't think you can write reliable code around this.

Comment: Since you're stuck with some junk for the DATE_OF_BIRTH column, if it's consistent junk and always appears in the DDMMYYYY format, then see the solution that Venkataraman R posted (the one with DATEFROMPARTS.  I have to tell you though, the birthdates that you've posted are all for people in the United States and a lot of folks here use the MMDDYYYY format.  You REALLY need to make sure.  Find someone with a DD or MM of more than 12.  That will actually define that column as the DD column.

Answer (score 3):

For date literals, you should put the year first, then month, then day, **ALWAYS**. So `06031987` should be `19870306`. *No exceptions.* `1987-03-06` is also permitted, but this still uses year, then month, then day. And for date-only values (with no time portion), the unseparated version is the better choice with Sql Server.

Anything else is still a string, and not a date at all. If you need a date you must convert it manually. This is possible, but it's slower and limited to formats shown in the documentation here:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Note that **none** of those formats match your desired `DDMMYYYY`. The closest you can get is `DD/MM/YYYY`, which isn't the same thing. This means you're down to parsing out string components into a new value that is compatible with one of those formats.

Finally, for completeness I need to mention the [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. This function will let you use the `DDMMYYYY` format, but it's only for converting dates to strings, not vice versa. It won't help you going the opposite direction.

Comment: As a bit of a sidebar, you should seriously avoid the use of the FORMAT() function in T-SQL.  In most cases, it's 43 times slower than even some exotic combinations of string functions and CONVERT.

Answer (score 2):

You can deal with bad formats if you can't change the source, but it's really, really ugly. Here are a couple of ways (there are at least a dozen ways to perform string manipulation and apply style numbers to make SQL Server understand and translate garbage into something you can use):

```
DECLARE @BadFormat varchar(10) = '06031987';

-- if it's mmddyyyy? June 3rd. Switch to yyyymmdd and use style 112.
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, RIGHT(@BadFormat,4) + LEFT(@BadFormat,4), 112);

-- if it's ddmmyyyy? March 6th. Make it dd/mm/yyyy and use style 103.
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(@BadFormat, 5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'), 103);
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67f831904020a1ba19533a8da0be0482)

But please, please, PLEASE try to fix the source to send you proper, unambiguous, non-regional formats. As Joel suggests, this is `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYYMMDD` only. `YYYY-MM-DD` *seems* safe, but it's not:

```
SET LANGUAGE Français;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '1987-06-13');
```

Result (not only in French but actually in over half of the languages SQL Server supports):

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3
> La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

For a lot more background, see:

- [How SQL Server handles the date format YYYY-MM-DD](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6770/sql-server-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-considerations/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Recommended SQL Server Date Formats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9315/recommended-sql-server-date-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [Build a cheat sheet for SQL Server date and time formats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate date value from the literal as given below:

```sql
declare @datevalue CHAR(8) = '06031987'

select DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(@datevalue,4),SUBSTRING(@datevalue,3,2),LEFT(@datevalue,2))
```

> 1987-03-06

Comment: Not only correct but one of the fastest methods there is.  Nicely done!

Comment: @JeffModen, thanks for your encouragement

Answer (score 0):

You most to convert the Italian or Spanish date "06031987" to a valid SQL date type format. The default is YYY-MM-DD, so you can implement a substring function to decompose this value '06031987'

```
SubString( @Date, 5, 4 ) + '-' + SubString( @Date, 3, 2 ) +'-' + SubString( @Date, 1, 2 )
```

Or make an user function like this.

```
Create Function dbo.fnConvertDMYtoSQLDate ( @Date VarChar( 8 ) )
Returns VarChar( 10 )
As
 Begin
  Declare @dt VarChar( 10 )
  Set @dt = SubString( @Date, 5, 4 ) +
            '-' +
            SubString( @Date, 3, 2 ) +
            '-' +
            SubString( @Date, 1, 2 )            
  Return @Dt  
 End
go
```

And call it so. `Select dbo.fnConvertDMYtoSQLDate('06031987')`.
In the insert you can use it so:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_ID,
                            CUSTOMER_OPEN_DATE, LAST_CUNSULTED_DATE,
                            VACCINATION_TYPE, DOCTOR_CONSULTED,
                            STATE, COUNTRY, DATE_OF_BIRTH, ACTIVE_CUSTOMER)
 VALUES('ALEX', '123457', '20101012', '20121013', 'MVD', 'PAUL', 'SA', 'USA', dbo.fnConvertDMYtoSQLDate('06031987'), 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DateString varchar(10) = '06031987';
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(@DateString,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/')),'-', '')
```

Comment: If the format of the original string were MMDDYYYY, that would be spot on.  However, if you look at the title of this post, the format is of the original string is actually DDMMYYYY.

Comment: Oh, Ok. My bad. Thanks.